# how can I modify a gmail account to forward an email that comes in with additional parameters?

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-imap

Say my gmail account gets an email, how can I make it so that any email that comes to my gmail account automatically forwards to another email "bob@gmail.com" with ADDITIONAL parameters in the body of the email? Do I have to use a php script with IMAP or can I do this with gmail alone?

Comment: Try asking this here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I used gmail's forwarding and filter options and the signature option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to do this reliably is through code.  So SMTP/IMAP to send & receive.  In Java you can use the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) api.  You'll need to find an equivalent package for PHP.

Comment: but how would I know to forward as soon as a NEW email comes in?

Comment: I have found my solution. I wish this wasnt closed but Ill share solution anyways. I used gmail's forwarding and filter options and the signature option